# From log file into terminal in realtime

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, logging, putty, stdout

I'm on Ubuntu.

Is it possible to open putty and watch as a log file updates right in terminal? Like if stdout would have been directed in terminal?

For example I have one application's stdout and stderr directed into a file and want to watch how my app is starting from another terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to follow a log file, you can use the famous:

```
$ tail -f /path/to/log/file
```

Comment: Damn forgot about tail :D ty again. Used it inside gltail.

Comment: @Beck: If you want to view the log while writing in the same terminal, you can use `tee`.

Comment: Perfect. For example if you have a homebrew installation of Apache httpd, you can open a terminal window and run 
tail -f /opt/homebrew/var/log/httpd/access_log
then load a web page from that server and see all the http transactions in real time.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to `tail -f`, you can also  [use **`less`** with the **`+F`** parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474/9382), which will allow you to keep track of new new input, but at the same time have access to all interactive functions of `less`, such as searching.

In some situations it is better to use **`tail -F`** (or **`less --follow-name`**) instead of `tail -f`. This assures that you continue following new input even if the file name changes. It is especially useful with some log-rotating software.

Comment: interesting, will check that out. have been thinking about such a feature...